# Is it bad style to name Ruby Constants using CamelCase?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Most Ruby constants follow the C convention of having all caps.

But is it considered legitimate style to name Ruby constants using CamelCase? I just think it is easier to type that way, since my Caps Lock is remapped to CTRL.

Comment: This question is a matter of opinion in the same way that wearing clothes in public is a matter of opinion.  You can break from convention in either case, but you won't have much company and you will surprise people.

Comment: @WayneConrad except you're less likely to get arrested from not using consistent casing than from not wearing clothes in public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the ruby specification, modules are constants. There is a philosophy behind it, and there is no reason they should be written differently. If modules are written in camel case, why not for the rest of the constants? Although writing in upper case seems to be the majority, I do write them all in camel case. In addition, writing in upcase reminds me of the classic languages like Basic, Fortran, etc., and does not look sophisticated.

ecologic points out compatibility with IDE, but if that causes a problem, then it's the IDE's bug. An IDE should follow the language's specification as strictly as possible, not the convention that people follow.

Comment: "writing in upcase reminds me of the classic languages like Basic, Fortran, etc." - LOLCODE CAN HAZ ALL CAPS!!1!

Comment: For the benefit of those new to Ruby, classes are subclasses of modules, and they also use CamelCase.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should ask to the people in your team and get a common decision, as you don't want two conventions in the same project.

In my opinion it's always a good idea to follow the proper convention of each language. I follow conventions that I don't really like. Also some IDE could interpretate the constant differently.

Comment: General readability gets worse for someone external, then if you decide to contribute to any opensource project, you will have to strive to go back to the regular convention.

Answer (score 2):

*No, it is not considered legitimate style to name "other" (non-class, non-module) constants using CamelCase.*

Standard Ruby practice is that classes and modules are CamelCase; other constants are SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE.

Ruby will permit you to use CamelCase for other (non class, non module) constants, but you will surprise *everyone* who reads your code.  The purpose of code isn't just to communicate with the machine, but to communicate with anyone who must understand your code.  For that reason, you should adhere to the widely accepted standard in this case.

## Evidence

All of the style guides I found on the first page of [a google search for "ruby style guide"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+style+guide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) which have anything to say on the matter support my claim that SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE is the overwhelming majority standard for naming non-class, non-module constants in Ruby.  A few quotes:

- https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case:

> Use SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for other constants.

- https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

> Use SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for other constants.

- http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#naming

> Constants should be named using all upper-case characters and underscores, e.g.
>
> ```
> BigFatObject::MAX_SIZE
> ```

- https://www.relishapp.com/womply/ruby-style-guide/docs/naming

> Use SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for other constants.